# Never give up on your hope vs Never give up your hope

Tags: grammar, prepositions, sentence-meaning

1. Never give up on your hope, whatever hardships you face.
2. Never give up your hope whatever hardships you face.

What's the difference between the two sentences in meaning? Are both 2 grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some more idiomatic expressions:

- Never give up, whatever hardships you face.
- Never lose hope, whatever hardships you face.
- Never give up on your dreams, whatever hardships you may face.
- Never give up hope, whatever hardships you face.

While the original sentences you mentioned make sense, they don't sound like the most standard English.

Answer (score 1):

To give up X (or give X up) is to surrender or abandon it.  (X can be a habit: “I gave up sugary drinks long ago.”)

To give up **on** X is to abandon expectation that X will have a good result.  “I gave up on that project; it was going nowhere.”  “My parents gave up on me after my second time in prison.”